# jquery submit event and return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

hi i check the blank field in the form and alert the user. but when alert the user it posts the data i couldnt return false not to refresh the page

```
$('#loginAccount').submit(function() {
    $(this).find(':input:text').each(function(i) {
        if($(this).val()=="") {
            // alert($('label').eq(i).html())
            $('#alert3').html('Please fill all fields.');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('#loginAccount').submit(function() {
    var valid = true;
    $(this).find(':input:text').each(function(i) {
        if($(this).val() == "") {
            // alert($('label').eq(i).html())
            $('#alert3').html('Please fill all fields.');
            valid = false;
        }
    });
    return valid;
});
```

You are currently returning from the each. What you need to do is track whether it's valid and then use that value as the return from your submit.

Comment: Thanks for this! Saves me from asking it myself. :)

Answer (score 5):

`return false;` takes on a different meaning inside of a jQuery each(). It is used to break out of the each. Maybe you could set a flag that is observed after the each() to see if the validation succeeded.

Comment: Thank you for this small explanation. I've had the same problem a while ago, I thought it was because the target page already started loading when javascript returns true, but i was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return false in the `submit` function, not the `each` function:

```
$('#loginAccount').submit(function() {
    var isValid = true;
    $(this).find(':input:text').each(function(i) {
        if($(this).val()=="")
        {
            isValid = false;
            //alert($('label').eq(i).html())
            $('#alert3').html('Please fill all fields.');

        }
    });
    return isValid;
});
```

Comment: This will always return false.

Answer (score 0):

May be you shoul use closure to return a value?

```
    $('#loginAccount').submit(function() {
           var result = true;    
            $(this).find(':input:text')
                 .each(function(i) {
                if($(this).val()=="")
                {
                    //alert($('label').eq(i).html())
                    $('#alert3').html('Please fill all fields.');
                    result = false;
                }
            });
            return result;
            })
```